# Elegant way to only include optional parameter if not null

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that receives 5 variables and calls a service that accepts 5 parameters which are all optional. If any of my received variables is `null`, I do not want to use it in the service call since service doesn't like that and throws me a GetFook'dException. I need to let the service fill in the blanks with its own default values (I know what they are, but they could be subject to change without my knowledge). For instance, if none of the variables are `null` I want to do this:

```
public List<Stuff> GetStuff(string type1, string type2, bool? isX, bool? isY, bool? isZ)
{
    return SomeService.GiveMeTheStuff(type1, type2, isX.Value, isY.Value, isZ.Value)
}
```

But if eg `type2` and `isY` are `null` I want to do this with named parameters:

```
public List<Stuff> GetStuff(string type1, string type2, bool? isX, bool? isY, bool? isZ)
{
    return SomeService.GiveMeTheStuff(type1param: type1, isXparam: isX.Value, isZparam: isZ.Value)
}
```

How do I go about doing this without going through all 32 possible variations of input?

Comment: Do you have control over `SomeService.GiveMeTheStuff`? What is/are the actual method signature(s) for `GiveMeTheStuff`?

Comment: I have no control over `SomeService`, this is the definition [from metadata]:
`List<Stuff> GiveMeTheStuff(string type1param = "%", string type2param = "%", bool isX = false, bool isY = false, bool isZ = false)`

Comment: Try this : type1param: type1 == null ? "abc" : type1

Comment: I don't know if this is elegant, but I would use reflection to determine the default values.

Comment: The usual decent cure for gothic method code is to use *one* argument.  An object of a small class or struct that stores the relevant info that you now try to squeeze into too many method parameters.

Comment: Default parameter values should not change if you can avoid it since already compiled assemblies will have baked in the previous default values into the call site. Only if you recompile everything will you get the new default values. If you want to have default values that are subject to frequent change you should provide constants for them in the same class and use the constants in the method declaration as well. This would at least give the programmer the ability to reuse the default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to use reflection in combination with `Type.Missing`:

```
public List<Stuff> GetStuff(string type1, string type2, bool? isX, bool? isY, bool? isZ)
{
    var type = SomeService.GetType();

    var flags = BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.Instance |
                BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |
                BindingFlags.OptionalParamBinding;

    var args = new object[]
    {
        type1 ?? Type.Missing,
        type2 ?? Type.Missing,
        isX ?? Type.Missing,
        isY ?? Type.Missing,
        isZ ?? Type.Missing
    };

    return (List<Stuff>)type.InvokeMember(
        nameof(SomeService.GiveMeTheStuff), flags, null, SomeService, args);
}
```